# ¿Cómo puedo buscar mas de un valor en una hoja de excel con textbox?, y ¿cómo puedo buscar en otra hoja en otra hoja de excel?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Ando tratando de hacer un buscador de un *datagridview* que importa desde *excel*. Pero me cuenta de 2 problemas.

Primero la forma que ando usando para buscar es la siguiente:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombres LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

Esta funciona correctamente. El problema está en que es solo para una columna en el `textbox_textchanged`. Al usar el mismo código, pero de distinto nombre de columna, este solo toma el valor de la que esté más abajo en el código.

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombres LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Apellidos LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

Por ejemplo, si está el código así, solo tomaría el segundo, que sería para la columna apellido.

También otro problema. Note que al tratar de buscar en otra hoja del mismo *excel*, el programa me da un error porque la tabla en la que trate de buscar no existía la columna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que busque en los dos columnas, entonces debes poner un `OR`

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
string.Format("Nombres LIKE '{0}%' OR Apellidos LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: tambien vi un problema de que cuando se trata de buscar en otra hoja del mismo excel al no tener por ejemplo la columna nombre en esta da error, esto igual se arregla con OR?